# IlSpy cannot be run as an app

Tags: windows, windows-store-app

once I installed IlSpy as a Windows-app. Unfortunately I made a system restore for a problem, which now has been solved.
The problem was a per-user-problem with OneDrive being set as storage location for the documents.
However now I am not able to run IlSpy as a App anymore. I just don't find the app in the programs in the start menu. A reinstall of the app isn't possible either, because the app is not shown in the list of the installed apps. Even in the Windows store I'm not able to run IlSpy as an app anymore.
So now: How should I proceed?

Comment: `A reinstall of the app isn't possible either, because the app is not shown in the list of the installed apps. ` There is no causal link here?

Comment: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases/tag/v8.2

Comment: What does the System Restore have to do with this? Windows can store more than one System Restore. Have you checked Event Viewer or other logs regarding this? When you run the app's executables, what do you see? Does Task Manager show anything?

Comment: @Gatendo If I'm not able to uninstall the app because of the missing entry in System Settings/Control Panel, I'm not able to install the app again. When I visit the Microsoft Store page of IlSpy, I just see a greyed-out word (Installed).

Comment: I don't see any link to the app and I'm not able to locate the executable.

Comment: `If I'm not able to uninstall the app because of the missing entry in System Settings/Control Panel, I'm not able to install the app again.`   Incorrect

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP stated the problem is fixed

Comment: It's a solution, so I don't think that means the Q needs closing.

Answer (score 1):

I repaired the installation of .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.27 (downloaded the .NET Desktop RunTime again in order to do that). Then I restarted my Computer and the app is now working again.